# Connect to server using NetClient with JsonParser only parses the first message

Tags: java, reactive-programming, vert.x, jsonparser

I'm writing a `ClientConnector` class using `NetClient` and `JsonParser`.

Here are the steps I went into:

1. Connect to server using `NetClient`
2. Use `Pump` to handle backpressure
3. Use `io.vertx.core.parsetools.JsonParser` to parse full *JSON* response objects
4. Write 2 requests on *socket*

The problem is that I get a server response only for the 1st request.

How can I get responses for subsequent requests?

Here down the [`AsyncClientConnector`](https://gist.github.com/shvalb/a50be68180e2b1db7012f2a0c463f8d2) class code:

```java
package com.luckyrhinos.sbg.robots;

import static io.vertx.core.parsetools.JsonEventType.VALUE;
import static org.awaitility.Awaitility.await;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.luckyrhinos.core.common.utils.RefHolder;

import io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.net.NetClient;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.net.NetSocket;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.parsetools.JsonParser;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.streams.Pump;

public class JsonRequestTest {

  @Test
  public void testName() throws Exception {

    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    NetClient client = vertx.createNetClient();

    RefHolder<NetSocket> hSocket = new RefHolder<>();

    AtomicBoolean ready = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    client.rxConnect(12344, "localhost") //
        .subscribe(socket -> {
          Pump.pump(socket, socket).start();
          JsonParser parser = JsonParser.newParser().objectValueMode();
          hSocket.obj = socket;

          socket //
              .exceptionHandler(e -> {
                e.printStackTrace();
                client.close();
              }) //
              .endHandler(v -> {
                System.out.println("Done!");
                client.close();
              }) //
              .handler(parser::handle);

          parser.handler(event -> {
            if (event.type() == VALUE) {
              System.out.println(event.value());
            }
          });

          ready.set(true);
        });

    await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).untilTrue(ready);

    ready.set(false);
    hSocket.obj.write("{ \"type\":\"SetupRequest\",\"ply\":2 }");
    hSocket.obj.write("{ \"type\":\"PingRequest\", \"id\":\"123456789\" }");

    await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).untilTrue(ready);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three issues:

- `Pump.pump(socket, socket).start();` does not do what you think it does. Maybe try deleting that. Don't "handle backpressure."
- Do not use a `RefHolder`. Just use a 1-length array here.
- Wrap your `obj.write` in a `vertx.runOnContext` call. You shouldn't use `vertx` objects outside of a `vertx` context. Or, examine the Vertx JUnit Test Runner and see if it meets your needs (this will give you a `TestContext` parameter for your test).

Without your server code, it's hard to tell if your server will correctly handle the two messages without a prefixed length argument (i.e., if you have a correctly-implemented equivalent of `JsonParser`).

You almost certainly want to use something like web sockets if you prefer a message model instead of a stream model. TCP is unsuitable, by itself without something like length prefixing, for the task you're suggesting you're using it for